# Clicking a moving object in a game

Tags: object, bots

I have made some very simple bots for some web based games and I wanted to move on to other games which require to use some more advanced features.

I have used `pyautogui` to bot in web based games and it has been easy because all the images are static (not moving) but when I want to click something in a game what is moving, it could be a Character or a Creature running around `pyautogui` is not really efficient because it looks for pixels/colors that are exactly the same.

Please suggest any references or any libraries or functions that can detect a model or character even though the character is moving?

Here is an example of something I'd like to click on:

[Moving creature Gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAzze.gif)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the image you linked to is a gif of a mob from world of warcraft.

As a hobby I have been designing bots for MMO's on and off over the past few years.

There are no specific python libraries that will allow you to do what you're asking that I'm aware of; however, taking WoW as an example...

If you are using Windows as your OS in question you will be using Windows API calls to get manipulate your game's target process (here wow.exe).

**There are two primary approaches to this:**

1) Out of process - you do everything via reading memory values from known offsets and respond by using the Windows API to simulate mouse and/or keyboard input (your choice).

1a) I will quickly mention that although for most modern games it is not an option (due to built-in anti-cheating code), you can also manipulate the game by writing directly to memory. In WAR (warhammer online) when it was still live, I made a grind bot that wrote to memory whenever possible, as they had not enabled punkbuster to protect the game from this. WoW is protected by the infamous "Warden."

2) DLL Injection - WoW has a built-in API created in LUA. As a result, over the years, many hobbyist programmers and hackers have taken apart the binary to reveal its inner workings. You might check out the [Memory Editing Forum on ownedcore.com](https://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/) if you are wanting to work with WoW. Many have shared the known offsets in the binary where one can hook into LUA functions and as a result perform in-game actions directly and also tap into needed information. Some have even shared their own DLL's

You specifically mentioned clicking in-game 3d objects. I will close by sharing with you a snippet shared on ownedcore that allows one to do just this. This example encompasses use of both memory offsets and in-game function calls:

```
using System;
using SlimDX;

namespace VanillaMagic
{
    public static class Camera
    {
        internal static IntPtr BaseAddress
        {
            get
            {
                var ptr = WoW.hook.Memory.Read<IntPtr>(Offsets.Camera.CameraPtr, true);
                return WoW.hook.Memory.Read<IntPtr>(ptr + Offsets.Camera.CameraPtrOffset);
            }
        }

    private static Offsets.CGCamera cam => WoW.hook.Memory.Read<Offsets.CGCamera>(BaseAddress);

    public static float X => cam.Position.X;
    public static float Y => cam.Position.Y;
    public static float Z => cam.Position.Z;
    public static float FOV => cam.FieldOfView;
    public static float NearClip => cam.NearClip;
    public static float FarClip => cam.FarClip;
    public static float Aspect => cam.Aspect;

    private static Matrix Matrix
    {
        get
        {
            var bCamera = WoW.hook.Memory.ReadBytes(BaseAddress + Offsets.Camera.CameraMatrix, 36);
            var m = new Matrix();
            m[0, 0] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 0);
            m[0, 1] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 4);
            m[0, 2] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 8);
            m[1, 0] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 12);
            m[1, 1] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 16);
            m[1, 2] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 20);
            m[2, 0] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 24);
            m[2, 1] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 28);
            m[2, 2] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bCamera, 32);

            return m;
        }
    }

    public static Vector2 WorldToScreen(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        var Projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovRH(FOV * 0.5f, Aspect, NearClip, FarClip);

        var eye = new Vector3(X, Y, Z);
        var lookAt = new Vector3(X + Matrix[0, 0], Y + Matrix[0, 1], Z + Matrix[0, 2]);
        var up = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);

        var View = Matrix.LookAtRH(eye, lookAt, up);
        var World = Matrix.Identity;

        var WorldPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);

        var ScreenPosition = Vector3.Project(WorldPosition, 0f, 0f, WindowHelper.WindowWidth, WindowHelper.WindowHeight, NearClip, FarClip, World*View*Projection);
        return new Vector2(ScreenPosition.X, ScreenPosition.Y-20f);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable information!
Didn't expect an answer so fast.
I'll read up on this and see if I can understand how it works, I know that Python can use the Windows API and I am quite sure that Python can do all of these things, I'll try to see if I can find out how!
I was also considering using OpenCV and some kind of Neural network to detect the 3D objects in-game, but I'll start by doing more research wih the information you provided, thanks again!

Comment: Hi again informedmoon. Yes, OpenCV is a pretty interesting library. I have used it for image processing, but I did not think to apply it to games with 3D environments. I feel like it's a unique idea to be sure.

Pixel reading is another visual way to create bots. Libraries I would suggest if you are using the Windows API are win32api and/or ctypes. They both expose the win32 api quite well.

Comment: Yea I'm hoping it will work, but at the moment all i'm doing is researching, a lot of planning before I can even write my first line of code ^^

Answer (score 0):

If the mobs colors are somewhat easy to differentiate from the background you can use pyautogui pixel matching.

```
import pyautogui
screen = pyautogui.screenshot()

# Use this to scan the area of the screen where the mob appears.
(R, G, B) = screen.getpixel((x, y))

# Compare to mob color
```

If colors vary you can use color tolerance:

```
pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (R, G, B), tolerance=5)
```